# How to retrieve a variable name given its value

Tags: python, class

```
class type_name:
    def __init__(self, *field_names):
        self.x = field_names[0]
        self.y = field_names[1]
        self._fields = [x for x in field_names]
    def get_y(self):
        return self.y

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        fstr = 'self.get_' + str(self._fields[ind]) #this would give me 5 i want self.y so I construct a string such as 'self.get_y()'
        #and then return eval on that string to return the value
```

Using this code above,

```
Point = pnamedtuple('Point', ['x','y'], mutable = False) 
origin = Point(0,5)
print(origin[1])
```

It should also work with origin['y']

Comment: Why not simply `return self._fields[ind]`?

Comment: Variable names are used to reference values, not the other way around. Of course, I'm sure there's a way to do it backwards, but you'd still be doing it backwards. Add `eval()` to this, and my recommendation is to take a step back and rethink your algorithm.